# Determine if scenario is running (Loadrunner)

Tags: windows, command-line, automation, loadrunner

I'm using Loadrunner 9.50 (for licensing reasons cannot upgrade to latest version)
Is there a way to dynamically determine, from command line, if a scenario is running?
I am writing a simple web app which will show if a workload is currently executing against a product and would like to check status using scripts.

I know, on Windows, that processes (using `tasklist`) called:

- `lr_host_balancer.exe`
- `lr_bridge.exe`

are running on generators, but this does not represent if a workload is actually running.
Is there a method/script I could use to return 'true' only if a workload is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an LG runs a load test it starts one or more processes called mdrv or mmdrv.
You can look for those. Note that they will not tell you who runs the load test on that LG only that some load test is running.

Comment: `tasklist | findstr mmdrv` did the trick. each team runs load using separate VM's which helps determine who's running load

Comment: You have now added a layer of complexity with VMs.  Make sure you have the updates and settings applied (if a VMWARE environment) to use the host hardware clock and not the VM clock for timing.  Also you will have to give up control of initial and in-test conditions for shared resource components.   This means you will have a higher test to test variability impacting repeatability and a wilder standard deviation for each test.

Comment: @Buzzy, Is there even such a thing as `mdrv.exe`? Isn't it only `mmdrv.exe`?

Comment: Some protocols use ````mdrv.exe```` and some use ````mmdrv.exe````.

Comment: Apparently the difference between the two is how the memory is allocated per each virtual user.

Comment: @Buzzy, Does the first 'm' stands for 'memory'? What exactly do you mean by "how the memory is allocated"?

Comment: @Pacerier IIRC the first 'm' stands for managed but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your request logs on your application under test.  More requests: Test Running.   No Requests: Test Not Running

Comment: this would not be reliable enough. what happens if multiple types of load are being driven against system or same load by diff teams .. how would you differentiate between them. querying load generators seems most reliable

Comment: If you have multiple teams trying to test the same application at the same time then you have very serious issues in uncontrolled initial and in test conditions that will impact your test reproducibility.  This id s process issue you need to address post haste

Comment: its a large test infrastruture with no exclusive access, minimizing access would reduce productivity. Tests range from build verification to load testing .. we're only interested in which teams are running load, the combined load causes no system issues.

Comment: @JamesPulley, For us, we don't have access to the AUT's request logs.

Comment: Then that is something you need to address with the application under test web infrastructure owner.